# Polymer CLI and Firebase: what is the best build model?

Tags: firebase, build, polymer-cli

Polymer CLI comes with several build options, including preset like es5-bundled.
I want to run my app on Firebase and have it compatible with older browser like IE11.
Are there specific build options that I should use?

Answer (score 0):

I am using gulp after watching a video from the Google Polycast series
[Building Firebase for production -- Polycasts #60](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByV3MWTa1fw)
But the basic Polymer build should work as well without extra build options.